# How to access javascript object fields by string name, getDeclaredField for javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to parameterize my javascript routine so I can pass the field name that I want to use to populate from the list I've got back from my JSON interface.
i.e, I want to convert my getRoutes() function (below) to getTable(), and pass the table name "Routes" and the field I want it to use, "routeId". "Routes" obviously isnt an issue as it's just passed to my JSON api, but how do I get "routeId" into the code ?. java has stuff like getDeclaredField, what's the javascript for that ?. I thought it was getValue, as in

```
    items.push("<option>" + val.getValue(keyName) + "</option>");
```

but that didnt work.

Here's my original working code that I want to generalise,

```
function getRoutes(){
    $.getJSON( "/GeeREST/Entity?entity=Routes", 
        function( data ) {
        var items = [];

        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            items.push("<option>" + val.routeId  + "</option>");
        });
    ...
```

And here's what I am trying to do

```
function getTable(tableName,keyName){
    $.getJSON( "/GeeREST/Entity?entity="+tableName, 
            function( data ) {
            var items = [];

            $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                items.push("<option>" + val.getValue(keyName)  + "</option>");
            });
 ...
```

Comment: Is `data[keyName]` what you are looking for?

Comment: Not sure but I think the square brackets would do the trick. You can do `var fieldname = "routeid"; var value = val[fieldname]` . Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Matt you busted me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple explanation:

```
var a = { 'b':1,'c':2};
$.each( a, function(key,val) {
   console.log(key,val,a[key]);
});
// Outputs:
// b 1 1
// c 2 2
```

So basically val is equal as a[key], and key is the key of the object we are iterating,
So in your case you should use val[keyName].